# Border of div bound to routerlink directive?

Tags: angular, routes, focus, ngfor, routerlink

I have encountered an issue where divs using routerLink get bordered with blue when clicked. I think I am missing something very obvious, possibly even a configuration I have in my browser or some missed css styling, so a polite explanation of the fix would be appreciated if so.

I've put together a basic demo of the issue here - https://github.com/DavidStreid/routingIssue. The code snippet creating this issue is at src/app/allGreetings.component.html and I put it below. Just download and "npm install; npm start" from the root, /routingIssue, to see the issue by clicking on the different greetings. I'm seeing this in chrome.

```
        <div *ngFor="let greeting of greetings" 
            class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="paddingDiv"
                [routerLink]="greeting.routerLink">
                        <h3 class="greetingType">{{greeting.title}}</h3>    
            </div>
        </div>
```

EDIT:
Here's an updated version from unitario's suggestion where I still see the blue border -

```
        <a *ngFor="let greeting of greetings" 
            class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <a class="paddingDiv"
                (click)="onSelect(greeting)">
                        <h3 class="greetingType">{{greeting.title}}</h3>    
            </a>
        </a>
```

SOLUTION:
From Shota Papiashvili. The outline comes from the focus selector. I don't want the border so I eliminated it and added another focus style -

```
    .paddingDiv:focus {
        outline: 0;
        background-color: black;
    }
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

its css outline property, this is very important for accessibility, you can read more at: http://www.outlinenone.com/

if you still want to do it just add

```
.paddingDiv:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

to your css

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much. This was troubling me all weekend. I'll take a look at the doc

Comment: Worked in Angular 9.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure which version of the router your are using but since version 3 you cannot use `routerLink` on any other elements than `a` or `button`.

If you need to use it in a `div` then use a `click` event together with `Router` and `navigate`.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately even when I removed the binding to routerLink and replaced it with your suggestion, I still see the blue border. I also tried changing the tag from div to a with the same result. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Yup, the approved answer will remove the outline from a specific selector.

If you want to remove the outline from all [routerLink] across the project then below CSS will more helpful.

```
 *[ng-reflect-router-link]:focus {
   outline: none;
 }
```

Comment: it works in chrome but not iOS app built with Ionic.

Answer (score 0):

just add this style in css:

```
.paddingDiv:focus {
   outline: none;
}
```

you can use it for every div that uses router link
or use:

```
 .paddingDiv:focus {
    outline: unset;
 }
```